# Two different uses of implicit parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit

(I am fairly new to Scala, hope this isn't a stupid question.)

From what I can see, declaring a parameter to a function `implicit` has **two** (related, but quite different) uses:

1. It makes explicitly passing a corresponding argument *when calling the given function* optional when the compiler can find a unique suitable value to pass (in the calling scope).
2. It makes the parameter itself a suitable value to pass *to other functions* with implicit parameters (when calling them from within the given function).

In code:

```
def someFunction(implicit someParameter: SomeClass) = {  // Note `implicit`
  ...
  // Note no argument supplied in following call;
  // possible thanks to the combination of
  // `implicit` in `someOtherFunction` (1) and
  // `implicit` in line 1 above (2)
  someOtherFunction
  ...
}

def someOtherFunction(implicit someOtherParameter: SomeClass) = {
  ...
}

implicit val someValue = new SomeClass(...)
// Note no argument supplied in following call;
// possible thanks to `implicit` (1)
someFunction
```

This seems somewhat strange, doesn't it? Removing `implicit` from line 1 would make both calls (to `someFunction` from some other place, and to `someOtherFunction` from within `someFunction`) not compile.

What is the rationale behind this? (**Edit:** I mean what is the *official* rationale, in case any can be found in some official Scala resource.)

And is there a way to achieve one without the other (that is to allow passing an argument to a function implicitly without allowing it to be used implicitly within that function when calling other functions, and/or to use a non-implicit parameter implicitly when calling other functions)? (**Edit:** I changed the question a bit. Also, to clarify, I mean whether there is a language construct to allow this - **not** achieving the effect by manual shadowing or similar.)

Comment: I think the 2nd, clarified, question has been answered by the fact that so much code contortion was required to demonstrate the requested conversions/restrictions.

Comment: "Also, to clarify, I mean whether there is a language construct to allow this" No, there isn't.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question

> What is the rationale behind this?

answers are likely to be opinion-based.

> And is there a way to achieve one without the other?

Yes, though it's a bit trickier than I thought initially if you want to actually use the parameter:

```
def someFunction(implicit someParameter: SomeClass) = {
  val _someParameter = someParameter // rename to make it accessible in the inner block

  { 
    val someParameter = 0 // shadow someParameter by a non-implicit
    someOtherFunction // doesn't compile
    someOtherFunction(_someParameter) // passed explicitly
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alexey. This makes sense, and answers what I asked, but does not quite answer what I _meant_ to ask :) Edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

The rationale is simple:

- What has been passed as explicit, stays explicit
- What has been marked as implicit, stays implicit

I don't think that any other combination (e.g. `implicit` -> explicit, let alone explicit -> `implicit`) would be easier to understand. The basic idea was, I think, that one can establish some common implicit context, and then define whole bunch of methods that expect same `implicit` variables that describe the established context.

Here is how you can go from implicit to explicit and back:

- Implicit -> implicit (default)

  ```
  def foo(implicit x: Int): Unit = {
    bar
  }

  def bar(implicit x: Int): Unit = {}
  ```
- Explicit -> implicit:

  ```
  def foo(x: Int): Unit = {
    implicit val implicitX = x
    bar
  }

  def bar(implicit x: Int): Unit = {}
  ```
- Implicit -> explicit: I would just use Alexey Romanov's solution, but one could imagine that if we had the following method in `Predef`:

  ```
  def shadowing[A](f: Unit => A): A = f(())
  ```

  then we could write something like this:

  ```
  def foo(implicit x: Int): Unit = {
    val explicitX = x
    shadowing { x =>
      // bar         // doesn't compile
      bar(explicitX) // ok
    }
  }

  def bar(implicit x: Int): Unit = {}
  ```

  Essentially, it's the same as Alexey Romanov's solution: we introduce a dummy variable that shadows the implicit argument, and then write the body of the method in the scope where only the dummy variable is visible. The only difference is that a `()`-value is passed inside the `shadowing` implementation, so we don't have to assign a `0` explicitly. It doesn't make the code much shorter, but maybe it expresses the intent a little bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey. This makes sense, and answers what I asked, but does not quite answer what I _meant_ to ask :) Edited the question to clarify.